# Why truncating the Power Iteration Method makes it more robust?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This paper [paper](https://icml.cc/Conferences/2011/papers/120_icmlpaper.pdf) (on page 3) says the following:

> If we truncate this method *(Power Iteration)* after some very small number, say 3, iterations, then the output vector is clearly a suboptimal approximation of the dominant eigen-direction of the particular matrix A; but due to the admixing of information from the other eigenvectors, it may be a better or more robust approximation to the best “ground truth eigen-direction” in the ensemble from which A was drawn.

Why is this truncation helpful in terms of robustness? I couldn't understand it from the quote above. Thanks!